# opening another application atomatically(in a loop one by one) in android

Tags: android, loops, android-intent

Is it possible to open another application from one application automatically in android without a button click and close it automatically after running it for some time say 3 mins and do this for other apps in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so.

Step 1: Getting list of application(package name) available in the device.

```
    final PackageManager pm = appApplication.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    List<String> pkgList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        try {
            packageInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageInfo.packageName, 0);

            // Adding packages installed in device in a list.
            pkgList.add(packageInfo.packageName)

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } 
    }
```

Step 2: Use "PackageManager" to open application wrt package name.

```
    // If not called from activity.
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    // Get package name from List and launch that package using intent. 
    Intent LaunchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgList.get(0));
    context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    context.finish();
```

Please feel free to revert of any query.